# Is there anyway to have conditional formatting look for text and date conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with a list of names and joining dates and another sheet with names and dates of people who have left. I am trying to add conditional formatting so that if someone leaves and rejoins later their name will not be highlighted.

The current code I have is '''=match(A3,indirect("Leavers!A3:A"),0)''' which highlights any names that are in both lists even if they rejoin later.

I don't wish to delete their name from the leavers sheet as we keep a record of why they left originally so that we can improve and try to avoid that reason from re-occurring.

Thanks.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that follows assumes the following:

1. That you'll be applying the CF rule to the first sheet, range A3:A
2. That your join dates are in the first sheet, range B3:B
3. That your leaving dates are in Leavers!B3:B

Custom CF rule:

`=VLOOKUP(A3,SORT($A$3:$B,2,0),2,FALSE)<IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,SORT(INDIRECT("Leavers!A3:B"),2,FALSE),2,FALSE),0)`

If any of the three assumptions are not the case, you'll need to adjust the rule/formula to match your own data set.

**How It Works**

The Column-A cell in question (`A3`) is `VLOOKUP`ed in a *reverse sort* of `A3:B` in the first sheet, returning the date (which will be the most recent). This is compared with a comparable `VLOOKUP` of the `Leavers` names and dates (i.e., reverse sorted). If the given name from the first sheet is not found in `Leavers` sheet, `IFERROR` assigns `0`. The rule will only take effect, then, if the most recent join date is less than the most recent "leave" date (if one exists).

However, because no sample spreadsheet was shared, this was written by eyeing it. If it does not work as expected, you will need to share a link to a sample spreadsheet.